# Letting user set default save directory via textfield

Tags: java, string, properties

Im aware that there are better ways, but I need to implement it like this for this application. Its supposed to be a practice for properties too.

I bound a textProperty *defaultDir* from  textfield inside a setDefaultDir Dialog, with the method `FileChooser.setInitialDirectory(new File(defaultDir.get()));` inside of my Save Dialog.

The binding itself works fine, I tested it by simply calling a printline of defaultDir right before calling setInitialDirectory(). So the problem must lie with how I input the text in my textfield.

I could not find anything on this online, usually I dont have problems googling stuff but I didnt find anything that would help me out. Since the binding seems to be working just fine, how does the user have to format the Directory in the textfield for this to work?   My "C:/User/Jonas/Documents" didnt work

Thanks in advance

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: TheFileChoser Open/Save dialog doesnt open in the directory I put in the textfield  even tho the binding seems to be working correctly.

Comment: When is `FileChooser.setInitialDirectory(...)` called at the beginning or each time the setDefaultDir Dialog is run.

Comment: I declared my FileChoser right on top of my controller class, and called FileChooser.setInitialDirectory(...)   on top of initialize(), but ofcourse after the binding

Comment: `FileChooser.setInitialDirectory(new File(defaultDir.get()))` is not a binding!

Comment: Im aware. But defaultDir was bound to the textproperty of the textfield earlier. As i wrote above. Thats the binding I was referencing to, sorry if that was unclear